# Vagrant share producing a 400 bad request

Tags: apache, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant with apache2 and specifically the command

`vagrant share --https 443`

It all starts fine and provides a URL. When I access that URL I'm presented with a 400 error:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at *.vagrantshare.com Port 443

I have been accessing the vagrant machine using https just fine, but it doesn't seem to like to work with vagrant share.

Comment: How does `your-project-name.conf` file looks like?

Comment: not sure if you solve it but [from doc](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/share/http.html) vagrant share by default looks for any SSL traffic on port 443 in your development environment. If it can't find any, then SSL is disabled by default. so making `--https 443` is redundant with the default config

Comment: @FrédéricHenri What should be the command then?

Comment: @itsazzad I think Frédéric is suggesting you can just use `vagrant share` and https traffic will automatically go to `:443`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Vagrant does exactly what it says when trying to establish the SSL port: it looks for traffic for what must be about 1 second and if it doesn't see any it disables HTTPS. This is obviously prone to failure in many SSL traffic environments, particularly development ones, so it seems to me that `--https 443` should be considered mandatory for reliable results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Vagrant Share bug: https://github.com/webdevops/vagrant-docker-vm/issues/51

The only workarounds I've seen discussed are to use a custom domain or to use another product entirely (e.g. ngrok) to create the share. See the bug discussion here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5493#issuecomment-159792794

Vagrant Share docs for custom domains are here: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/vagrant/shares/custom-domains